# Signed triangulations of simplicial polyhedra

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Let $\partial S$ be the boundary of a compact polyhedron $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, assumed to be generic, in the sense that every face of $S$ is a triangle, and so that there are exactly two triangles on every edge. Thus $\partial S$ is a triangulated oriented surface, with sets of vertices $V$, edges $E$ and triangles $T$.

Not every $S$ may be traingulated, that is, partitioned into tetrahedra (i.e. full-dimensional simplices), with vertices from $V$ --- a simple example of such $S$ is [Schönhardt polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron). However, the latter may be sign-trianguled, i.e. decomposed into the difference of two unions of tetrahedra with vertices from $V$: just take its convex closure (an octahedron, a convex polytope, thus it's possible to triangulate it using vertices from $V$ only), and the disjoint union of 3 tetrahedra.

The conjecture is that such a signed triangulation is possible for any $S$ - I have a sketch of a proof by induction on $|V|$, but perhaps it is well-known?

Weaker forms of this conjecture, in terms of measures, allowing real weights of simplices, or just integer weights, is known to hold in all dimensions, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3193 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07594

Comment: What if you fix a vertex $v$ and take all tetrahedrons with this vertex $v$ and base formed by triangle $\triangle \not\ni v$?

Comment: then you end up with a convex shape, so in general this won't work. It is tempting to try to take into account the "orientation" of $\Delta$ w.r t. $v$, to choose the sign accordingly, but then one has to prove that every point in the interior of $S$  is covered the right number of times, etc...

Comment: Well, I assume that if a tetrahedron comes with negative orientation, then you have to subtract it.

Comment: yes, that's what I basically do, and to keep track of overlaps, I use a moment generating functiuon representing $S$ as in https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3193

Comment: Dima, did you find any more on this question? I am also interested. Thanks.

Comment: It gets a bit messy with $\partial S$ having "singularities", i.e. vertices or even edges not lying on one side of $S$, but otherwise it works. 

I've been too busy with childcare, job search, etc etc since late 2019 to finish papers :-(

Comment: Hey, that's where I am, too! Childcare, job search, trying to write papers.